# PHP dynamic layouts

Tags: php, dynamic

Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

My question is how can i have a static header/ footer and only the main content change. Also I want to know how i can keep the URLs SEO friendly?

One other thing is in my site say the section is web hosting the url i want would be http://example.com/web-hosting. No when that page loads I want there to be a side bar in the content that would be specific to web hosting and this would change depending on what top level category they are in.

If you could point me aat a tutorial or reading resource Id much appreciate it.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Sounds like you want a CMS system.

Comment: You should ask one question at a time otherwise if you get 'right' answers for the questions you have asked from different people which one would you mark as accepted? Split this question into separate questions and go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish on each one.

Comment: sorry still getting the hang of posting on here :)

Comment: @Tyler he certainly is, Sometimes the best code you'll ever write, is the config file for someone else's code. ;)

Comment: No need to be sorry just trying to help out. Everyone benefits from direct, to the point questions that have accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any frameworks, what you'd do is have the code for each static segment in its own file, then include the files where appropriate in each individual page.  Or, you could always just group everything into 'header.php' and 'footer.php', and include those onto every page.

If you're looking for something with a little more infrastructure, you can take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com).  You'll have to read through the tutorials a bit, but it provides a framework to create each different visual block of your page once, then incorporate them into individual pages as needed.

Comment: SEe WHMCS does all the database calls, so I don't know what else I could use the controller for in codeigniter, cake, etc..

Answer (score 0):

What I do to keep header/footer same is I create a separate PHP file called `pageElements` which contains functions for navigation menu, header and footer. On every page, I include that file and call those functions.

This is the simplest way, in my opinion.

Comment: so would the function be some thing like this $element = $_GET['element']; include($element.".php"); I know this is very basic but is that the kind of idea you mean ?

Comment: No. The `$_GET` variable is used for GET method URL requests. Your function could be something like this: `getElement($element_name)` and the function body would be something like: `{ include_once($element . '.php'); }`

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into Smarty for templating your site out - I was against it but lets you seperate login from presentation.

the the url part, Apache mod_rewrite (available to most people!) will do that for you.

basic example of a .htaccess file (put in the htdocs of the site) - will re-write anyfile/path that does not physically exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

in your index.php (or whatever) user $_GET to access what was sent to use to direct your code.

Comment: was actually thinking of using smarty as WHMCS uses that but i've never used it so dont really know anything about it is there any videos, reading material, or tutorials that you can recommend. Plus what does that htaccess stuff mean?

Comment: I'm just leaving the office now - but can comment more tonight if i get a chance or tomorrow if that helps - I can send you some snippets of Smarty/php to get you started. Unledd you need anything complicated you dont need a cms/framework :) if you can wait till later I can show more detail :)

Comment: hi brian my email is admin@amazinghost.co.uk give me a we message once your back :) Speak Soon :)